# Irreducible link complements in $\mathbb S^3$

Tags: manifolds, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Let $L$ be an oriented link in the 3-sphere $\mathbb S^3$, consisting of two knot components, $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. I wonder now if the following is true:

*If the linking number $N(L)$ of $L$ is not $0$, then $S^3 \setminus L$ is an irreducible 3 manifold.*

This is equivalent to showing:

*If there is a smoothly embedded 2-sphere $\Sigma \subset \mathbb S^3$, with $\Sigma \cap L = \emptyset$, such that $\gamma_1$ is contained in a different component of $\mathbb S^3 \setminus \Sigma$ than $\gamma_2$, then $N(L) = 0$.*

I had the following idea: In the closed 3-ball $B_1$, whose interior is the component of $\mathbb S^3 \setminus \Sigma$ containing $\gamma_1$, perform an orientation-preserving self-homeomorphism that is the identity on $\Sigma$. This can be naturally extended to a self-homeomorphism on all of $\mathbb S^3$ by the identitiy on $\mathbb S^3 \setminus B_1$. Call the resulting map $h$ and let $L'$ be $h(L)$. 
I want to find $h$ such that there exists a regular projection of $h(L)$ such that $h(\gamma_1)$ and $h(\gamma_2)$ will have disjoint images under that projection. So far this hasn't worked out for me. Can anyone give me a hint ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to show that having a sphere in the complement that separates the two link components allows you to construct disjoint Seifert surfaces. Start with a Seifert surface for one component. It will hit the sphere in a union of circles which can be surgered along inner most disks to make the Seifert surface disjoint from the sphere. Now do the same procedure for the other link component. Once you have disjoint Seifert surfaces, the linking number is trivial, which can be seen by using the fact that the linking number is the algebraic intersection number of the seifert surface of one component with the other component.

Comment: Is there a good reference paper where it is shown that the linking number of two closed curves in $\mathbb S^3$ always equals the algebraic intersection number of any seifert surface of one curve with the other curve ? So far I haven't found anything on this...

Comment: I don't know a reference off the top of my head, but here's a sketch of a proof. First show it is true for the standard Seifert surface coming from a plane diagram by identifying the intersections diagrammatically. Then argue that it is true for an arbitrary Seifert surface, which differs from the standard one by a sequence of "S-equivalences." An S-equivalence gives a cobordism from one surface to another, and the intersection of the second component with this cobordism will be a set of arcs which pair up the intersection points. Let me know if this is too vague.

Comment: Also, I realized there is another proof of your original statement. Use the Schönflies Theorem to make the sphere standard. Then it is is more or less obvious that there is a projection where the two components don't corss.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: Do you really need Schoenflies for this? Seems like all you really want is Alexander's theorem that every $S^2$ in $S^3$ bounds a ball. (Not that Schoenflies is far off from Alexander.)

Comment: @MikeMiller: Sure you can probably get away with Alexander's theorem. Once you have that ball contract it until it is far away from the other link component.

Comment: That would be precisely the isotopy i was looking for. Note that I was assuming Alexander's theorem already in the statement of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an argument based on another (standard) definition of linking number: Recall that the first homology of a knot complement is freely generated by a meridian $\mu$ for the knot (i.e. a curve bounding a small disk transverse to $K$). More precisely, there's an isomorphism $H_1(S^3 \setminus K)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ given by $[\mu]\mapsto 1$.

**Definition.** *If $K'\subset S^3$ is a knot disjoint from $K$, define the* linking number *of $K'$ and $K$ to be the integer $n$ such that 
$$[K']= n \cdot [\mu]$$
as classes in $H_1(S^3 \setminus K)$*.

Now we want to show that if $K$ and $K'$ are separated by an embedded 2-sphere $\Sigma \subset S^3$, then their linking number is zero. As you wrote in your original post, $\Sigma$ separates $S^3$ into a pair of 3-balls. Letting $B$ denote the ball containing $K'$, we see that the inclusion $i:S^3 \setminus K \hookrightarrow (S^3 \setminus K,B)$ induces an isomorphism $H_1(S^3 \setminus K) \cong H_1(S^3 \setminus K,B)$ using the LES associated to the pair $(S^3 \setminus K,B)$. We also note that the homology class of $K'\subset B$ vanishes in $H_1(S^3 \setminus K,B)$. Thus, since $i_*([K'])=0$ and $i_*$ is an isomorphism, we conclude that $[K']=0$ in $H_1(S^3 \setminus K)$ as desired.

---

**Edit:**

For the first statement, see [The first homology group $ H_1(E(K); Z) $ of a knot exterior is an infinite cyclic group which is generated by the class of the meridian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550846/the-first-homology-group-h-1ek-z-of-a-knot-exterior-is-an-infinite-cycl)

For the equivalence of the homological and diagrammatic definitions of linking number, consider any regular diagram for $K \cup K'$. Define a new link $K''$ as follows: At each crossing where $K'$ passes over $K$, replace the overstrand with an understrand and add a small meridional loop around $K$. Here's the local picture at a positive crossing:

[image]

The local picture for a negative crossing is similar, with the orientation on $K$ reversed. It is easy to check that $lk(K',K)=lk(K'',K)$ using the diagrammatic definition. Note that each meridional loop contributes either +1 or -1 to $lk(K'',K)$ based on whether it came from a positive or negative crossing. It is also straightforward to convince oneself  that $K'$ and $K''$ are homologous in $S^3 \setminus K$. (There's an obvious annulus spanned by pushing $K'$ straight down, and we get the meridional loops by cutting out holes for $K$ to pass through. The resulting surface lies in $S^3 \setminus K$ and has boundary $K' \sqcup -K''$.) Now $K''$ consists of a bunch of meridional loops and a disjoint component which lies entirely underneath $K$. We can modify the diagram by pulling the latter component out from under $K$, so that it clearly does not contribute to the diagrammatic linking number. This means that the diagrammatic linking number of $K''$ and $K$ is a *signed* count of the meridional loops. Similarly, since the "large" component of $K''$ bounds a Seifert surface disjoint from the rest of the components and $K$, it does not contribute to the homological linking number. This means that this latter linking number is also a signed count of the meridional loops, and it's clear that the two signed counts agree (assuming $\mu$ is a positive meridional loop). Since $K''$ is homologous to $K'$ in $S^3 \setminus K$, we conclude that the two definitions of linking number are the same.

Comment: Note that this argument is pretty low-tech and can be used even if you don't know Alexander's sphere theorem. It's easy to see that any smoothly embedded $S^2 \subset S^3$ separates $S^3$ into a pair of 3-manifolds $U$ and $V$, each possessing $S^2$ boundary. Van Kampen's theorem implies that $\pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V) \cong \pi_1(S^3)$, so $U$ and $V$ are simply-connected. Now the original argument works with $B$ replaced by whichever of $U$ or $V$ contains $K'$.

Comment: This argument, however, relies on the fact that your definition of linking number is equivalent to the standart definition, with a regular diagram. Still a nice answer! Also, how exactly do you prove the statement from the first paragraph ? I know that $S^3 \setminus K $ is diffeomorphic to the interior of a solid torus if and only if $K$ is the unknot. But how do you compute the first homology in the other cases?

Comment: @BerniWaterman: Agreed. Do those edits clear it up?

Comment: I should note that the definition of linking number using the complement of one component is pretty much the same as the algebraic intersection number definition I gave. The seifert surface is poincare dual to the meridian of the first component.

Comment: The only thing that keeps your answer from being absolutely perfect is the fact that you should call $K''$ a link, rather than a knot, as it is a collection of disjoint closed curves. Other than that, well done, and thank you for your efforts!

Comment: @ Grumpy: One has to be a bit careful when talking about Poincaré-duality, as one has to specify what the compact, ambient 3-manifold should be. The most reasonable choice would be to take $M:= \mathbb S^3 \setminus D_1$, where $D_1$ is an open tubular neighborhood of $\gamma_1$ that is disjoint from $\gamma_2$. Now, replacing $\gamma_1$ by an appropriate projection $\gamma_1'$ on $\partial D_1$, we can think of the seifert surface $S_1$ of $\gamma_1$ being properly embedded in $M$. This means that there are fundamental classes $[\gamma_2] \in H_1(M)$ and $[S_1] \in H_2(M,\partial M)$.

Comment: Now let $\alpha \in H^2(M, \partial M)$ and $\beta \in H^1(M)$ be the Poincaré duals to the classes mentioned above, and let $\mu_{(M,\partial M)}$ be the (relative) fundamental class of $M$. The *algebraic intersection number* $i(\gamma_2,S_1)$ can then be defined as $(\alpha \cup \beta )(\mu_{(M,\partial M)})$. Is this what you mean by intersection number, or is there an easier way to define it (For example, using de Rham cohomology) ?

Comment: @BerniWaterman: yes that's the construction. The algebraic intersection number can also be calculated as an actual signed count of intersections between representatives of the classes after they have been perturbed to be transverse.

Comment: In the latter case, however, how can one be sure that one has chosen representatives that intersect minimally among all suitable choices ?

Comment: @BerniWaterman: Minimality isn't necessary because the intersection count is signed. It's similar to the fact that a regular diagram need not be minimal when using the diagrammatic definition.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the distinction between geometric and algebraic intersection. Thanks for reminding me.